# Adobe Acrobat Reader DC Icon Inconsistency

Tags: windows-10, pdf, icons, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I've read the similar questions and answers regarding the Adobe Reader icon showing up incorrectly. I did find that the icon was coming from the Windows 10 Default App Settings for Photo viewer.

I have followed the steps in the post to remove and replace the icons, but that didn't work. I uninstalled and reinstalled Reader. Now, the icon is correct on the taskbar, the desktop and in the Start Menu tiles. It is incorrect when I click on the Start Menu list of apps, while staying correct in the other locations. Thoughts? I'm all out.

Screen grab of Start list:

[image: Start List]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Start, Settings, Apps

Scroll down for Choose Default Apps by Protocol and ensure Acrobat is properly associated.

Go back scroll down for Choose Default Apps by File Type and ensure PDF and PDX are associated with Adobe.

Ensure that any occurrence of Photos (Photo Viewer) is not associated with Adobe files.

Restart after the above changes have been made.

I have two Windows 10 machines here - one with Reader and one with Acrobat and they both associate correctly

Comment: Thanx John. I had previously confirmed my settings were correct for the Default Apps. I'm not technically savvy enough to ensure that any ocurrence of Photos is not associated with Adobe files. I would presume that this would take a lot of time, unless you know of a shortcut.The issue has been resolved

Comment: Thanks. Other than the above, I am not aware of any other shortcut